# Use name instead of IP address to access home network behind a router

Tags: networking, router, ssh

Here is a rough drawing of my network map. Everything is working swimmingly. Bash Alias' are all set up and ssh keys are exchanged.

I can access my home server via user@staticExternalIP1 -p < portNum > from where-ever I want. How could I set up access to my server using user@serverName.com from anywhere rather than remembering my IP address?

```
-> My modem 

     -> staticExternalIP1, on router 1
         -> Windows PC 1 (PC 1 internal IP)
         -> Server 1 (Server 1 Internal IP, accessible via port forward)

     -> staticIP2 on router 2
         -> home wifi
```

Comment: "from anywhere" - Define what you mean by "anywhere".  Your server would be accessible by using your public ip address.  You can use a hostname by modifying the hosts file for your OS.  However, your IP address is likely NOT static, which means you would have to update it every time it changes.  There are dynamic DNS providers, but specific recommendations of services are outside of the scope here at Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound. By anywhere I mean, anywhere. It is currently accessible by using my public IP address. My IP(s) is static. I requested 2 IP's from my ISP and they were nice enough to give me them. Static no less. Sorry, it looks like I explained all of this above. I'm simply looking for an explanation on how to access it by user@serverNameOfMyChoosing.com instead of user@myipaddress.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thank you for the suggestion, but this looks like a solution for a dynamic DNS. Should I not simply be able to use a google public DNS with settings in my router and host file on my server to rename some things (as my IP is static)?

Comment: Hmmm, I think you may be confusing global vs private DNS. If you have a static IP, buy a domain and direct it to your IP number. And you don't have to use noip.com dynamic DNS. In this case you would just point the name to your IP. This shouldn't be difficult...